# Which verb form goes with "sweat"?

Tags: american-english, verb-agreement

I just love the way the sweat **glistens** off your back in the sun

I just love the way the sweat **glisten** off your back in the sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically: sweat is uncountable- you can't have "five sweats". So it's treated as a singular. Use **glistens**.